# VB.Net Kinect Mouse

Tags: vb.net, kinect

I have a question here that was answered by "Evil Closet Monkey" regarding a Kinect mouse project, i converted the code from C# to VB.Net. The code is as follows:

```
Private Sub TrackHandMovement(skeleton As Skeleton)
    Dim leftHand As Joint = skeleton.Joints(JointType.HandLeft)
    Dim rightHand As Joint = skeleton.Joints(JointType.HandRight)

    Dim leftShoulder As Joint = skeleton.Joints(JointType.ShoulderLeft)
    Dim rightShoulder As Joint = skeleton.Joints(JointType.ShoulderRight)

    Dim rightHip As Joint = skeleton.Joints(JointType.HipRight)

    ' the right hand joint is being tracked
    If rightHand.TrackingState = JointTrackingState.Tracked Then
        ' the hand is sufficiently in front of the shoulder
        If rightShoulder.Position.Z - rightHand.Position.Z > 0.4 Then
            Dim xScaled As Double = (rightHand.Position.X - leftShoulder.Position.X) / ((rightShoulder.Position.X - leftShoulder.Position.X) * 2) * SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth
            Dim yScaled As Double = (rightHand.Position.Y - rightShoulder.Position.Y) / (rightHip.Position.Y - rightShoulder.Position.Y) * SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight

            ' the hand has moved enough to update screen position (jitter control / smoothing)
            If Math.Abs(rightHand.Position.X - xPrevious) > MoveThreshold OrElse Math.Abs(rightHand.Position.Y - yPrevious) > MoveThreshold Then
                RightHandX = xScaled
                RightHandY = yScaled

                xPrevious = rightHand.Position.X
                yPrevious = rightHand.Position.Y

                ' reset the tracking timer
                trackingTimerCounter = 10
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

i already imported Microsoft.Kinect

now i have these errors showing:

'xPrevious' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
'MoveThreshold' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
'yPrevious' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
'MoveThreshold' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
'RightHandX' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
'RightHandY' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
'xPrevious' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
'yPrevious' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
'trackingTimerCounter' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

I know that they are not declared and really don't know what to do, can anybody help me out with this?

sorry for my ignorance

Comment: Can you link to the article you got this code from?  I might go back and make a few corrections to that code. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are global variables, which need to be defined outside of your function.

`xPrevious` is last position your hand was at as the function exits.  It is referenced again when the function runs again to see if your threshold has been exceeded.

`yPrevious` is the same as above, just for the `y` coordinate.

`MoveThreshold` is the amount your hand must move in either the `x` or `y` axis for the function to recognized it has moved.

So, outside your function you should have something like...

```
Dim xPrevious As Double
Dim yPrevious As Double
Dim RightHandX As Double
Dim RightHandY As Double
Dim MoveThreshold As Double = 0.04
```

(it has been awhile since I coded in VB, so my declarations above may be a little off)

That said, I don't handle jitter control that way anymore.  I use the built in functionality which does a much better job then my little hack job up there.  For jitter control you should something like the following declared when initialize your Kinect sensor:

```
new TransformSmoothParameters
{
    // as the smoothing value is increased responsiveness to the raw data
    // decreases; therefore, increased smoothing leads to increased latency.
    Smoothing = 0.5f,
    // higher value corrects toward the raw data more quickly,
    // a lower value corrects more slowly and appears smoother.
    Correction = 0.5f,
    // number of frames to predict into the future.
    Prediction = 0.5f,
    // determines how aggressively to remove jitter from the raw data.
    JitterRadius = 0.05f,
    // maximum radius (in meters) that filtered positions can deviate from raw data.
    MaxDeviationRadius = 0.04f
};

sensor.SkeletonStream.Enable(this.TransformSmoothParameters)
```

(above is C# code)

The `trackingTimerCounter` is a timer that is running in the background.  If it runs out then the user hasn't moved their hand in over 10 seconds, so the hand cursor is hidden until they move again.  Just remove that line.

With the above points your posted function would change to:

```
Private Sub TrackHandMovement(skeleton As Skeleton)
    Dim leftHand As Joint = skeleton.Joints(JointType.HandLeft)
    Dim rightHand As Joint = skeleton.Joints(JointType.HandRight)

    Dim leftShoulder As Joint = skeleton.Joints(JointType.ShoulderLeft)
    Dim rightShoulder As Joint = skeleton.Joints(JointType.ShoulderRight)

    Dim rightHip As Joint = skeleton.Joints(JointType.HipRight)

    ' the right hand joint is being tracked
    If rightHand.TrackingState = JointTrackingState.Tracked Then
        ' the hand is sufficiently in front of the shoulder
        If rightShoulder.Position.Z - rightHand.Position.Z > 0.4 Then
            Dim xScaled As Double = (rightHand.Position.X - leftShoulder.Position.X) / ((rightShoulder.Position.X - leftShoulder.Position.X) * 2) * SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth
            Dim yScaled As Double = (rightHand.Position.Y - rightShoulder.Position.Y) / (rightHip.Position.Y - rightShoulder.Position.Y) * SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight

            RightHandX = xScaled
            RightHandY = yScaled
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

`RightHandX` and `RightHandY` now tell you where the cursor should be placed on the screen.

I do all this slightly differently now, but the above should still function to translate your hand position to a point on the screen.

P.S.
Never apologize for ignorance, it is where we all started from.  Ask questions; it is how we all learn. :)

Comment: thanks a lot buddy i appreciate it, previously i purchased the Gesturepak SDK to get everything easily and it worked like charm, but when it came to mouse movements it was lacking the API in the documentation so i couldn't get it to run thats why im searching for it, btw im a dentist thats why im not realizing all the coding perfectly, anyways thaaanks a a lot :)

Comment: another question, this code still uses (the left and right shoulders) as the right and left sides of the screen and (the head and pelvic) as the top and bottom of the screen?

Comment: Yes.  Head/Hip = Top/Bottom of the screen.  Left Shoulder = Left side of screen.  The right side of the screen is your right shoulder, plus the distance between your shoulders (so about half an arm length).